# Sending Records Using INDY

Tags: delphi

How can i send a record in Indy TIDTCPServer (version 10.5.8 )

Many examples for previous version shows us

```
AThread.connection.WriteBuffer(MyRec,SizeOf(MyRec),true); // myrec is a record
```

but what is the equal command in indy 10.5.8

```
IdContext.Connection.IOHandler.?????
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the `RawToBytes` function to convert a buffer to a `TIdBytes` (which is the type that accepts the Write method)

Check this sample.

```
uses
  IdGlobal;

var
 Buffer : TIdBytes;
 Myrec  : TMyrec;
begin
  Buffer := RawToBytes(Myrec, SizeOf(TMyrec));
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write(Buffer);
end;
```

Comment: Another option is to write the record to a `TMemoryStream`, or use Indy's `TIdMemBufferStream`, and then pass it to the `TIdIOHandler.Write(TStream)` method.

Comment: I meant `TIdMemoryBufferStream`.